# Elasticsearch Unique field

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I want to store urls in an index but I want unique url.

I'm making POST request to store my documents but I want to avoid duplicate document based on the url field.

Is there a way to specify a unique constraint on the url field ?

I have around 5 million of data so I don't want to make  url as the document ID instead as it will slowdown my search query.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `_id` is the only field that can have the uniqueness restriction. You probably know this but a new document with existing id would override the existing document with same id. You can use `op_type=create` or `/my_index/my_type/ID/_create` in order to get back an error if a document with same id already exists.

Comment: If I   generate my own id e.g. bb03ecb36e0577ba13c453063f2b07e0 will it effect my search query because I have close to 5 million records.

Comment: It depends on the query. Are you going to search by `_id`?

Comment: No, I will search by title and description. _id will be only used for updation.

Comment: Then I don't think there will be issues.